# how can I open ms document to windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ms-word

I have my msword.doc in the app iso storage. The question how can I open this in the built in ms word in windows phone 7?

Comment: Windows Phone 7 SDK currently does not support this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the current Windows Phone 7 SDK.

A workaround could be to upload your document to a web server then access it via a `WebBrowserTask`. The OS will then open the document in the built-in Word.

Comment: is there other way like converting ms docs to some format so the silverlight can read it?

Comment: I googled some answers and found that I can use some converter to convert documents (ms docs,pdf) into xps, and use xps viewer.Will try to look at it.